Wilcoxon Matched-Pair Signed-Rank and Correlation (Pearson, Spearman, or Kendall)
According to the publication Extracting Pre-Post Correlations for Meta-Analyses of Repeated Measures Designs https://matthewbjane.quarto.pub/pre-post-correlations/ , if the value of the t-statistic from a paired t-test is available, the Pearson correlation between pre and post scores in related samples can be calculated.
pre_mean <- 12.62
pre_sd <- 3.845
post_mean <- 18.33
post_sd <- 5.155
paired_t <- 10.52
n <- 78

r <- (paired_t^2*(sd_pre^2 + sd_post^2)-n*(post_mean-pre_mean)^2) /                                                            
      (2*paired_t^2*sd_pre*sd_post)
   
r

It is also mentioned that the Pearson correlation can be calculated from the p-value of a paired t-test.
pre_mean <- 12.62
pre_sd <- 3.845
post_mean <- 18.33
post_sd <- 5.155
pval <- 1.5e-16 # from a paired t-test
n <- 78

# get paired t from p value
paired_t <- qt(pval/2, n-1, lower.tail = FALSE)

r <- (paired_t^2*(sd_pre^2 + sd_post^2)-n*(post_mean-pre_mean)^2) /
  (2*paired_t^2*sd_pre*sd_post)

I found a similar question on the website
Extraction Pre-Post correlation of repeated measures design
but I could not find the answer that I am looking for.
Question: Can these formulas be extended to the Wilcoxon signed-rank test and its corresponding p-value? If we know the p-value after running the Wilcoxon signed-rank test (or even have access to the W statistic), can we calculate the correlation (Pearson, Spearman, or Kendall)?
Question: If we have a large sample size, can we say that the results of the Wilcoxon signed-rank test and the paired t-test tend to converge? Because if the answer is yes, maybe I can put the p-value (from the Wilcoxon signed-rank test) in the formula for calculating the correlation (based on the p-value of the paired t-test).
note: In the field of meta-analysis (in repeated measures design), the value of correlation (Pearson, Spearman, or Kendall) is necessary to calculate the effect size. We have access to some information (such as mean, standard deviation, p-value, and type of test—whether it is paired t-test or Wilcoxon signed-rank test), but none of the publications provide the value of correlation between pre and post scores. We need to find a way to calculate the correlation values from the information we have. Some references provided formulas to calculate the correlation from the available values of t-statistics and p-value after running the paired t-test. So, I am looking for a way to calculate the value of correlation (Spearman, or Kendall) for those publications that applied the Wilcoxon signed-rank test.

I thought my comments in the duplicate thread were pretty clear ;-).

Neither rank-correlation measure will correspond to the signed rank test in general; the correlation measures are purely rank based but the signed differences used in the signed rank test are data-based. Whether something like that  might work with Kornbrot's rank difference test is less immediately clear; perhaps there's a connection to a measure of rank correlation there.

@Glen_b, Thank you so much for the comment. I just modified the question to provide more info. But If we have a large sample size, can we say that the results of the Wilcoxon signed-rank test and the paired t-test tend to converge? Because if the answer is yes, maybe I can use the formula based on the p-value of the paired t-test to calculate the correlation instead.

What does "tend to converge" mean? It is best to think that different tests and measures answer different questions. Their results will often be consistent, but it's not helpful to regard them as interchangeable.

@whuber, thank you so much for the comment. I just added a new question about the equivalency of the paired t-test and Wilcoxon signed-rank test in large sample sizes. I would be thankful if I could have your thoughts and advice.

@Nick Cox, thank you so much for the advice. I thought maybe we could end up with approximately the same p-value from both the paired t-test and the Wilcoxon signed-rank test for large sample sizes. Maybe I can put the p-value (from the Wilcoxon signed-rank test) in the formula for calculating the correlation (based on the p-value of the paired t-test).

I can't follow your drift here. If you have access to the original data, it is easy to run whatever tests or calculate whatever measures you like and see how far they give similar results. In a report most readers would expect some clarity on your goals and on which test or measure is closest to those.  Otherwise P-values are fragile reeds and can't be used to get at other results unless the procedure is exactly the same underneath, which isn't true of any two procedures you mention. If you don't have access to data, there isn't much you can do to get one kind of result from another.

This is becoming harder to follow and more unfocused as you add extra material. I appreciate that the context is meta-analysis and that usually the original data are not available, but that's not an excuse for cavalier assumptions. The answer from Thomas Lumley is, unfortunately for your question, on target as indicating that the goal here is illusive as well as elusive.

@Nick Cox, thank you so much for your time. Yes, we don’t have access to the data; we just have access to the summary statistics and the p-value corresponding to applying a test. That is why I was thinking maybe there is a scenario where the paired t-test and Wilcoxon signed-rank test could be equivalent, and I could use the above formula to calculate the correlations.

Unfortunately this is just wishful thinking. With some effort you could find a situation in which you get the same P-value, but the two tests are not  in general equivalent in any sense but that of comparing two groups.  I think you're getting the same message out of this thread -- and crucially also from the CV thread you cite -- from several people now.

@Nick Cox, again thank you so much for your time

It's easy to see that you can't get the Pearson correlation, because it doesn't depend only on the ranks as the Wilcoxon signed-rank test does.
It is not obvious whether you can get the Spearman correlation, but this experiment shows you can't
> x<-1:10
> y<-runif(10,1,10)
> cor(x,y,method="spear")
[1] -0.01818182
> cor(exp(x),exp(y),method="spear")
[1] -0.01818182
> wilcox.test(x,y,paired=TRUE)

    Wilcoxon signed rank exact test

data:  x and y
V = 22, p-value = 0.625
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

> wilcox.test(exp(x),exp(y),paired=TRUE)

    Wilcoxon signed rank exact test

data:  exp(x) and exp(y)
V = 19, p-value = 0.4316
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0


We have two data sets of the same size that give the same Spearman correlation but different Wilcoxon signed rank test results.
